# Django dynamic folder name based on id/username when uploading image

Tags: django

Good day SO.

I want to make my folder name(s) to be renamed based on the ID/username of the uploader.

My setup is as follows:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
     username= models.CharField(...) # As per our setup, user cant enter their own username but will be auto created based on a separate py file on my view during registration
     ...

class Type01Account(models.Model):
    account = models.OneToOneField(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    imgPath = ""   
    images= models.ImageField(upload_to=imgPath, null=False, blank=False)
```

How should I assign imgPath? Should I assign it on models or on view? If so, how should I save it?

Answer (score 6):

The upload_to argument can be a function which takes the model instance and filename and returns the path to upload:

```
def img_path(instance, filename):
    return f"{instance.account.username}/{filename}"

class Type01Account(models.Model):
    account = models.OneToOneField(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    imgPath = ""   
    images= models.ImageField(upload_to=img_path, null=False, blank=False)
```

Reference: [FileField.upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)

Comment: Hey. Sorry I took so long to reply. is the function img_path under Account? If yes, on Type01Account, img_path is not defined error message is returned when I save the py file. If under Type01Account, NoneType' object has no attribute 'username' when II upload images.

Comment: @rodjames img_path would be in the **same** file as `Type01Account` and just above it. Also NoneType object has no attribute 'username' means that when you are saving the instance of `Type01Account` you are not setting the `account` attribute of `Type01Account` to an instance of `Account`

Comment: Before I added this def img_path, there is no NoneType error message when I save. After I added img_path, it is now rendering the error message. Maybe my view.py has something wrong in it. Let me check.

Comment: I got it. Instead of instance.account. just instance

Comment: Hello its me again. The `return f"{instance.account.username}/{filename}"` is working on registration but on my update, (Same Form different view).

Comment: It returns a `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'`

Comment: @rodjames Your instance appears to not have an account yet, How do you assign it? Assign it **before** saving the object.

Comment: nvm. I fixed it in a hacky way. Since I have instance.id, I used it to retrieve the username.

Answer (score 0):

A class to handle the all `upload_to` for any field that contains a file

```
import os

from django.utils import timezone


class UploadTo:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __call__(self, instance, filename):
        base_filename, file_extension = self.generate_name(filename)
        path = f'files/{instance.__class__.__name__}/{self.name}/{timezone.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d")}/{base_filename}{file_extension}'
        # any custom action on path
        return path

    def generate_name(self, filename):
        base_filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
        # any custom action on file name
        return base_filename, file_extension

    def deconstruct(self):
        # you can add some static value from model like `self.name`
        return 'path.to.this.UploadTo', [self.name], {}

# Usage example
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    # add here some static value to class `news_image`
    news_image = models.ImageField(_("news image"), upload_to=UploadTo('news_image'), blank=True)
```